# python regular expression grammar

Tags: python, regex

```
... html ...
[{"url":"/test/test/url","id":"111111"},{"url":"/test/test/url","id":"111111"},    {"url":"/test/test/url","id":"1111"}]
.... html ...
```

I have some json type string in html.

How make rex expression to extract pattern as

"/test/test/url" and "1111" comes after "id":

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @EricHotinger I tried for 3 hours and also use regex generator tools :(

Comment: [^\"url\"\:\"](.*)$\" this one is my best try :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with @Haidro's answer on this, but if you want to use a regex, or see how you would, then here's some sample code:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\"url\":("[^"]+"),\"id\":("[^"]+")')
match = re.finditer(regex, yourString)

for m in match:
    print m.group(1), m.group(2)
```

`[^"]` is a character class for accepting all non- `"` characters.

**EDIT:**
I love how I recommend the other answer, but explain how to do it if one really wants to know, yet I somehow still get downvoted.

Comment: I was going to put almost the exact same answer. I think some people blindly think of the "don't use regex for html" diatribe any time they see the two words together... (P.S. I don't think you need to escape the quotes in the regex)

Comment: @Haidro Some people just like downvoting, I guess...

Comment: @SteveP. Eh, bets to just leave it to be honest. It's their one reputation they're loosing :P

Comment: @beroe Yeah, I understand that there's no reason to recreate the wheel, especially if you're not going to do a better job, but nonetheless, this is pretty simple and I'm not sure that it's horrible to use a regex, and OP seems to have wanted a way to figure out how to do it using a regex, so I figured I would help.  F**k me, right?

Comment: @Haidro Yeah, it doesn't really bother me all that much.

Comment: Yeah, but you came out with a net gain because I gave you an upvote... ;^)

Comment: @joseph No problem.  Good luck.  Regex's can be complicated, but once you get more experience, they become easier.

Comment: @SteveP. I don't know why people downvote on the question and answer. it's not inquire about Json but people think that way and they really don't read question at all :(

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regular expressions here, use the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. This is what it's designed for.

```
import json
mylist = json.loads(html)
for subdict in mylist:
    print subdict['url']
    print subdict['id']
```

Comment: it's json type string, but it's in html. so, I cannot decode to json directly.

Comment: @joseph What do you mean it's in html? You use `json.loads` on strings

Comment: it's not clean json string. it's in html file. When I use json.loads, python cannot decode it.

Comment: @joseph Try `json.load` instead of `json.loads`